# flutter Upgrading issue "var response = aawait stream.pipe(ioRequest) as HttpClientResponse;"

Tags: flutter

(updating flutter SDK on the stable channel to 3.3.0),
when running `flutter upgrade` I am facing this error:

```
Building flutter tool...
.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.4/lib/src/io_client.dart:44:23: Error: Expected ';' after this.
      var response =  aawait stream.pipe(ioRequest) as HttpClientResponse;
                      ^^^^^^
.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.4/lib/src/io_client.dart:44:23: Error: The getter 'aawait' isn't defined for the class 'IOClient'.
 - 'IOClient' is from 'package:http/src/io_client.dart' ('.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.4/lib/src/io_client.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'aawait'.
      var response =  aawait stream.pipe(ioRequest) as HttpClientResponse;
                      ^^^^^^
```

I have checked my internet connections and used multiple VPNs and still the same.

Comment: Have you tried fixing your cache

Comment: `io_client.dart` in your cache somehow has a typo in it, perhaps from corruption or from an inadvertent edit.  Clear your cache with `dart pub cache clean` or repair it with `dart pub cache repair`.

Comment: thanks, cleaning and repairing the cache solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`io_client.dart` in the cache somehow has a typo, probably due to corruption or an unintentional edit. Clear the cache with `dart pub cache clean` or fix it with `dart pub cache repair`.